# Prevent Raspberry Pi From Sleeping

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, screen

want to prevent Raspberry Pi from going to sleep I tried below mentioned Solution but my pi is going to sleep every 10 min.

I am using Raspbian OS with Raspberry Pi 2

1.I installed xscreensaver and disabled it

2.I added xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms to sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.also test it by changing to xserver-command=X -s 0 dpms.

3.I added consoleblank=0 to sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt.

Nothing works can any one help me for this?

Comment: where in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` did you add that?

Comment: have you tried everything in https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=202859 ... exactly as stated in that thread

Comment: @JaromandaX at the last I added the lines and Yes I tried Everything from Link you provided

Comment: `I added the lines` ... **where**

Comment: I added the line in end of file

Comment: is it in the correct section? (I can't see your file, so you'll need to be more specific) i.e. is it in the `[SeatDefaults]` section

Comment: yes i checked it with [SeatDefault] but its not working